# unable to reference Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages

Tags: c#, sharepoint, dll

Can anyone tell me what using statement or DLL I neeed to include in my C# project so I can include Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.Pages?

Answer (score 0):

Had to manually copy Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel out of the GAC and add a reference to it. I was able to add it as a using statement and it worked without any issues.